# How to resolve the warning on my homepage, after deleting mini panel?

Tags: panels

I deleted a mini panel and then created a new one and on the homepage I keep getting a warning message and I don't understand why.

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value in panels_renderer_ipe->render_pane_content() (line 145 of E:\inetpub\wwwroot\modules\panels\panels_ipe\plugins\display_renderers\panels_renderer_ipe.class.php)

Please can someone explain why this happens? This is quite confusing ...

Comment: Do you still have the pane attached to your homepage? Panels is probably still trying to render the pane that doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi, no I thought I deleted all my panes. I even get this message as well

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in template_preprocess_page_manager_edit_page() (line 42 of E:\inetpub\wwwroot\modules\ctools\page_manager\theme\page_manager.theme.inc).

Comment: Deleting the pane is different from removing it from the panel that's using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your problem is caused by what is detailed in the issue about [PHP 5.3.9 Strict Warning on Panels Empty Value](https://www.drupal.org/node/1632898). It was first reported in Panels 3.2, and has status 'Closed (Fixed)'.

The patch in comment # 15 of it should help you resolve the error. And according to comment # 26, this patch is included as of Panels 3.4.